# How do I get this command to work with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I can't get this command to work with subprocess:

```
tail -f -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log | grep -Ev ''mnt|^$'
```

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess

tail = subprocess.Popen('tail -f -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log | grep -Ev ''mnt|^$''', shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = tail.stdout.readline()
    line = line.strip('\n')
    print line
```

Nothing prints to screen. However when I type the tail command in shell - it works perfectly fine and I receive output:

```
root@jumpbox:~# tail -f -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log | grep -Ev 'mnt|^$'
Sep 14 16:06:35 x.x.x.x : %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19, changed state to administratively down
Sep 14 16:06:35 x.x.x.x : %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19, changed state to administratively down
```

I have a feeling it either doesn't like the quotes or the pipe?

Answer (score 2):

This string literal:

```
'tail -f -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log | grep -Ev ''mnt|^$'''
```

Is effectively three separate single-quoted strings run together:

```
'tail -f -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log | grep -Ev '
'mnt|^$'
''
```

So the actual command you're executing is:

```
tail -f -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log | grep -Ev mnt|^$
```

Which isn't at all what you wanted - note that you're piping the output of `grep` to a nonexistent `^$` program!  Basically, it was pure coincidence that this turned out to be syntactically valid at all.  You either need to use a different form of quoting for the overall string (double quotes would work in this case), or escape the inner quotes with backslashes.

Comment: Doing this: "tail -f -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log | grep -Ev 'mnt|^$'" also doesn't work... But I understand your explanation now....